# Django 2.1.7 ! Шаблон не выводит переменную

Tags: python-3.x, django

1) Объявляю переменную `b = {'days': "test"}`
2) Передаю ее в шаблон `return render(request, 'guests/form.html', b)`
3) В шаблоне просто хочу вывести `<p>{{ days }}</p>`
4) Смотрю код страницы, а там в нужном мне месте `<p></p>`

Как пофиксить? Почему не читает переменную?

view.py:
`class Guests(View):
    def get(self, request):
        b = {'days': 'test'}
        return render(request, 'guests/form.html', b)`

urls.py:

```
`from guests.views import Guests
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Guests.as_view()),
]`
```

Answer (score 1):

А покажите пожалуйста полностью представление из `views.py` и что у вас в `urls.py`. Вероятно вы подключаете в `urls` какое то другое представление в котором у вас нет словаря с ключом `days`.

Comment: ` def get(self, request):`     
        `form = GuestsForm() `   
       ` b = {'days': test} `      
        `return render(request, 'guests/form.html', b)`

Comment: @Axesthump, вы мне не функцию класса скидывайте, а представление - это какой то класс где ваша функция get используется, мне нужно понять от какого класса наследование вы делаете. Насколько я понял вы используете CBV, там это делается иначе.

Comment: Отредактировал сам вопрос, посмотрите там

Comment: @Axesthump я уже увидел, сейчас ответ напишу.

Answer (score 1):

@Axesthump 
Это с использованием класса `View`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

class Guests(View):
    def get(self, request):
        b = {'days': 'test'}
        return render(request, 'path_template', b)
```

Тут у вас должно всё работать, у меня работает.

Я бы на вашем месте использовал класс `TemplateView`, и тут уже следует делать вот так.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class Guests(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path_template'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Guests, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['days'] = 'test123'
        return context
```

Сам шаблон я не изменял.

```
<p>{{ days }}</p>
```

Ну и URLconf тоже прежний.

```
from my_app.views import Guests

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Guests.as_view()),
]
```

Надеюсь вам это хоть как то поможет.